# Is there any company who helps to come into UK to work from outside EU/EEA with Tier 2 Working visa sponsorship?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, nepal

I have a friend in Nepal who is a lab assistant, working in a hospital. She would like to come to UK to work, but lab assistant is a low paid job (Band 2) in the UK so no company/hospital would sponsor her.

Is there any company who helps ppl come to UK live&work legally?

Comment: It seems unlikely. If employers are not paying enough to sponsor her directly, it seems unlikely they would pay enough to both cover the cost of sponsoring her and allow a profit for another company.

Comment: About sponsoring I meant: accepting her in the UK. I would pay my friends visa, plane ticket, accomodation, etc. I just need a company which want to employ her.

Comment: Even if a company want to sponsor a low paid job, home office will not issue a visa on that ground. Please take a look at minimum annual wage for tier 2 and point based system.